# running Django web application publicly on the web

Tags: django, python-3.5

i'ev finished making a chatbot web application using Django and python3 and during the development phase i was using the:

```
    python3 manage.py runserver
```

to see the results and test the application. Now i want for the application to entered like any other website publicly using URL.

any recommendation for deploying the django project?

thank you?

Comment: Not the type of question for stack overflow. Lots of options. Look at AWS elastic beanstalk or Heroku for simple solutions, with django examples.

Comment: Or if you mean that you do have a hosting provider but don't know how to deploy, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your hosting provider. Heroku is a good choice, it has a free pricing tier but that tier brings the VMs down if not used regularly.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Answer (score -1):

It may be a good idea to start with the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/